# C: iterate with for-loops, a ceil statement and odd vs even statements

Tags: c

I am a relative beginner with C.  I have written what I think is a fairly simple 
C program to iterate a variable ‘season’ inside two for-loops.  The code compiles 
and runs, but ‘season’ is not being tracked correctly.  I am hoping someone may be 
willing to offer suggestions on how to correct the code.

Below I provide the results I would like, the current C code, and the results that code
is returning.

I would like the following results:

```
cohort = 1, class = 1, season = 1
cohort = 1, class = 2, season = 1
cohort = 1, class = 3, season = 2
cohort = 1, class = 4, season = 2
cohort = 1, class = 5, season = 3
cohort = 1, class = 6, season = 3

cohort = 2, class = 1, season = 1
cohort = 2, class = 2, season = 2
cohort = 2, class = 3, season = 2
cohort = 2, class = 4, season = 3
cohort = 2, class = 5, season = 3

cohort = 3, class = 1, season = 2
cohort = 3, class = 2, season = 2
cohort = 3, class = 3, season = 3
cohort = 3, class = 4, season = 3

cohort = 4, class = 1, season = 2
cohort = 4, class = 2, season = 3
cohort = 4, class = 3, season = 3

cohort = 5, class = 1, season = 3
cohort = 5, class = 2, season = 3

cohort = 6, class = 1, season = 3
```

My C code follows immediately below and after that I present the 
results returned by the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
char quit;

main()
{

int mcoht, mclass, season, nmcohts ;
double season2, cohort2, class2 ;

nmcohts = 6 ;

// cohort loop

for (mcoht=1; mcoht <= nmcohts; mcoht++) {

     season = ceil(mcoht/2) ;

  // class loop

  for (mclass=1; mclass <= (nmcohts-(mcoht-1)); mclass++) {

    season2 = season ;
    cohort2 = mcoht  ;
    class2  = mclass ;

    printf("cohort is:  %10.10lf\n", cohort2);
    printf("class  is:  %10.10lf\n", class2);
    printf("season is:  %10.10lf\n", season2);

    // update season (mclass&1) = 0 if mclass even, 1 if mclass is odd 

    if(((mcoht&1) + (mclass&1)) == 1) season = season + 1; 

  } // close class loop

} // close cohort loop

  printf("To close type 'quit' and hit the return key\n");
  printf("               \n");
  scanf("%d", &quit);

return 0;

}
```

Here are the results returned by the code.  Unless I made a mistake
typing the lines below it looks like 'season' is correct for the 
even-numbered cohorts, but is 1 less than needed with the odd-numbered 
cohorts.

Thank you for any suggestions either regarding how to correct the code or how
to improve this post.

```
cohort = 1, class = 1, season = 0
cohort = 1, class = 2, season = 0
cohort = 1, class = 3, season = 1
cohort = 1, class = 4, season = 1
cohort = 1, class = 5, season = 2
cohort = 1, class = 6, season = 2

cohort = 2, class = 1, season = 1
cohort = 2, class = 2, season = 2
cohort = 2, class = 3, season = 2
cohort = 2, class = 4, season = 3
cohort = 2, class = 5, season = 3

cohort = 3, class = 1, season = 1
cohort = 3, class = 2, season = 1
cohort = 3, class = 3, season = 2
cohort = 3, class = 4, season = 2

cohort = 4, class = 1, season = 2
cohort = 4, class = 2, season = 3
cohort = 4, class = 3, season = 3

cohort = 5, class = 1, season = 2
cohort = 5, class = 2, season = 2

cohort = 6, class = 1, season = 3
```

I put code-sample quotes around the results only to display them as columns.  I do not need the output to be formatted as shown.  I simply need 'season' to be calculated correctly.

Comment: I am a self-taught newby.  Please feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  This has been extremely helpful and educational.  I will also look into possibly obtaining ‘The C Programming Language’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised this hasn't been answered in half an hour...

The problem you're having with the `ceil()` function is that you're using integer operands for the division.  The way C does division with operands that are both integral is that it will produce an integer result, truncating any fractional part.

Therefore, `1/2` gives a result of `0`, not `0.5`.

If you want a floating point result, you need to force at least one of the operands to be floating point. So instead of:

```
ceil(mcoht/2)
```

try

```
ceil(mcoht/2.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, sincerely.  This has been very helpful.

Comment: still doesn't fix using floating point math on integers unnecessarily

Answer (score 1):

And few more things besides the `ceil` function:

1. Statement `season2 = season;` is superfluous, because the `season` is already in the scope  of the inner `for` loop.
2. You do not need `double`s.
3. As per C99 standard, you shouldn't omit the function's (`main`'s in your case) return type. And although you *can* omit `main`'s parameters, you'd better put `void` there.
4. Adding a few spaces around the operators would help as well.

Comment: Good comments. ceil() can be replaced by `mcoht/2 + 1` in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to implement your suggestions.  Would it be appropriate for me to post here asking for suggestions on the best C reference book for somebody learning the language on their own?

Comment: @MarkMiller, some would say that you should take [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) ... if think you'll be better off with a newer book: (1) filter the books by the year (have them be at least from 1999/2000 onwards, so that they take into account the C99 standard), (2) check the reviews.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into obtaining 'The C Programming Language'.

Comment: I just ordered the book and the solution manual.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the call to `ceil` completely, there is no need to convert things to double, make a function call and convert back. If I see this correctly integer arithmetic with `(mcoht+1)/2` would be completely sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The variable names meant nothing to me so I just changed them to a b and (and c wasn't needed) and used while loops instead (just personal preference).  It looks like the object of this lesson is to find the pattern using mod and/or div (column 3 is column a + column b div 2)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int a=0, b, num=6;
while (a++<=num) { b=0;
    while (b++ <= (num-a))
        printf("cohort is:  %d class  is:  %d season is:  %d\n", a, b,(a+b)/2);
}
return 0;
}
```